# Modify front-end HTML live with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, cross-site

I'm using a search engine's web API for my app, and I need to use it in the form of POSTs. I realized that I can only POST to the API from the site itself. I looked at a node.js wrapper for this, and it uses 'requests' module. So I have 3 questions:

1. Is there a way I can get around needing a back end, and make the POST requests right from the page?
2. Can I use a Node module in a front end-only app? As in, the module is running on the page, updating it live?
3. If not, how does one modify the front end live, through the Node back end server? As in, some method is called using the Node module and the HTML responds without reloading the page?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't make an ajax request from your site to the API?

Comment: I tried that multiple times, but got an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering each of your questions in order:

1. Depends on the  search engine.  It might be possible if they support JSONP.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
   There's a few other potential solutions, but to be honest the 'cleanest' solution if they don't support JSONP is to use a back-end to serve as a proxy.
2. Node runs on a computer, in its own runtime, not in the browser.  You'll need to host the Node process somewhere, and it has to be in the some origin that's serving your html files (unless you implement a JSONP interface), but it does not have to be the process that serves your static HTML and JS files.
3. You'll have to have javascript running on the page that makes the Ajax request to the Node application, and then modifies the page based on what it gets back.